# What does "light touch with brushes" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

This is a part of a Wikipedia page about the drummer "Shadow Willson"

"The drummer was known to sit in at the famed Minton's Playhouse.[3] His nickname came from "his beautiful **light touch with brushes**,"

**light touch**
2. A relaxed, humorous, or easygoing way of doing or approaching something.
*The director handles the heavier themes of the film with a light touch.*(source thefreedictionary.com)

**brushes**
2. either of a pair of wire-bristled, brushlike devices used to mark a soft rhythmic beat on drums or cymbals.

Does it mean that he was playing the drums with brushes in a relaxed and easygoing way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is literal.

He was able to play the drums with brushes touching the drum skin very gently (ie "lightly") to create a beautiful quiet sound.

Playing quietly is harder than playing loud.  Anyone can hit a drum, but it takes skill to touch the drumskin lightly.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

**Light touch with brushes** means that he didn't use a lot of force or pressure when playing with the brushes. He applied only light pressure to give a soft, gentle sound.

You might refer to this as a **relaxed** way of playing, but **relaxed** really refers to his arms and wrists being in a relaxed position to enable this very soft and gentle playing technique.

Comment: I'm a drummer! I'm not sure why you downvoted me, but my answer is correct.